# Data table echo from sql statement php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I executed 2 sql querys and need to put them in the table according to the results returned, my code is:

```
<table id="dataTableExample2" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sıra</th>
            <th>Kategori</th>
            <th><?php print date('Y'); ?></th>
            <th><?php print date('Y', strtotime("-1 year")); ?></th>
            <th><?php print date('Y') . " %"; ?></th>
            <th><?php print date('Y', strtotime("-1 year")) . " %"; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $count = 1;
            while ($count < 12) {
                mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTable);
                mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTableTwo);
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
                echo '<td>$count</td>';
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

could you guys help me to fix the code so that in every while loop iteration I create a `<tr>` `</tr>` tag and echo results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to increase $count at the end of the while loop.

second, save the result of each fetch_assoc in a variable, then you can access that variable

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
while($count<12) {
    $var1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTable);
    $var2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTableTwo);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$var1['someColumn'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var1['otherColumn'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var2['foo'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var2['bar'].'</td></tr>';
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: what about <tr> </tr> tags since tr tags determine the row how can i echo so that every while loop iteration is a row